# SQL foreach table and get number for duplicate data using reference date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains two fields name and date

```
+-------+------------+
| name  | date       |
+-------+------------+
| B     | 28-09-2015 |
| A     | 28-09-2015 |
| B     | 29-09-2015 |
| A     | 29-09-2015 |
| B     | 30-09-2015 |
| A     | 30-09-2015 |
| B     | 01-10-2015 |
| C     | 01-10-2015 |
| B     | 02-10-2015 |
| B     | 03-10-2015 |
| C     | 03-10-2015 |
| B     | 04-10-2015 |
+-------+------------+
```

I went compare date now with date for my data and get this table

```
    +-------+------------+
    | name  | Number     |
    +-------+------------+
    | A     | -4 day     |
    | C     | -1 day     |
    | B     | 0 day      |
    +-------+------------+
```

Thank you

Comment: Please explain your logic in some detail.

Comment: i went get the last record of any name and compre his date with date now and get how much day i have deference

Comment: What type is your date column?

Comment: type of column date is datetime

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @Ruydo Are you sure it's not of type `DATE` or `TEXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to get a list of the newest dates. You can use this with `MAX(date)` but that alone will just get you the newest date in the table. You can tell the database you want the newest date *per name* with a [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause. In this case, `GROUP BY name`.

```
SELECT name, MAX(date)
FROM names
GROUP BY name
```

Now you can do some date math on `MAX(date)` to determine how old it is. MySQL has [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to get the difference between two dates in days.  [`CURRENT_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) gives the current date.  So `DATEDIFF(MAX(date), CURRENT_DATE())`.

```
SELECT name, DATEDIFF(MAX(date), CURRENT_DATE()) as Days
FROM names
GROUP BY name
```

Finally, to append the "days" part, use [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(DATEDIFF(MAX(date), CURRENT_DATE()), " days") as Days
FROM names
GROUP BY name
```

You can [play around with it in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49124/12).

I would recommend *not* doing that last part in SQL. You won't get the formatting quite right ("1 days" is bad grammar) and the data is more useful as a number. Instead, do the formatting at the point you want to display the data.

Answer (score 3):

You should `group by` each name, get the `max` date and use `curdate()` to get the difference. Use `DATE()` to convert from from `datetime` to `date` for calculation.

```
select name, max(DATE(datecolumn)) - curdate()
from tablename
group by name
order by max(DATE(datecolumn)) - curdate()
```